# How to find class name or id name of any element on a page?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the name of id and class of any element and if it does not have any id or class then it should return null.

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(ele){
});
```

I have used this code to get the element clicked by the user.

How to get the id or class name if present using this "ele" element ?

Comment: `ele.target.id` or `ele.target.className` - `ele` is not an element, it is an [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)

Comment: Just addition over Aruns comment..Current/clicked element can be found using `this` in handler...

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry ! i tried but could not find @FelixKling Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to get the id or class name if present using this "ele" element ?

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(ele){

   alert("id is " + this.id );
   alert("class is " this.className);

});
```

but this event is on the document, you won't get individual ids.

For that you need to bind an event to all elements of the document

```
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
for ( var counter = 0; counter < allElements.length; counter++)
{
   allElements[counter].addEventListener('click',function(ele){

       alert("id is " + this.id );
       alert("class is " this.className);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the JS way then you can do :

```
              document.addEventListener('click',function(event){
                   var id =event.target.id;
                   var className=document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("class");
                alert(id);
                alert(className);
                   });
```

If you want to go with Jquery way : then

```
                $(div).click(function(event){
                      alert($(this).attr("class"));
                      alert($(this).attr("id"));
                 });
```